# Will a Worker Tier always be at CPU 100% Load?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I have a web crawler running on Elastic Beanstalk Worker Tier and I have it going on all times. When the queue is empty, it just loads in all new url's again and it keep going and going. It's never empty.

My CPU load is on 100% using a micro instance no matter how many threads or processes I have it set on, and I'm getting a bit confused about this and I would love to hear some input.

Is it "normal" that the CPU will be at 100% when the SQS is loaded? I guess that the instance will keep reading messages from the SQS as soon as one message is finished, so that means that even if I would upgrade my instance to a small, or large instance it would still be at 100% CPU load, the only difference would be that it could do more messages in the same amount of time. Correct?

Second question is if there is any big issue with having 100% CPU load? In the log, sometimes I get Timeout errors such as `Script timed out before returning headers: application.py`. I guess this could be related to too high load(?), if so, can I prevent it or lower the CPU load somehow?

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to move from t1 micro instance to t2 micro instance.

Answer (score -1):

When you run top, what is the ST value?

The example below the steal value is 0.0%

```
top - 13:01:16 up 161 days, 22:49,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks:  88 total,   1 running,  87 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1695600k total,  1585988k used,   109612k free,   345484k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   527696k cached
```

I believe it's because you are using a Micro instance where you are not paying for access to all of the underlying CPU cycles. Amazon won't give you access to 100% of a modern, fast CPU when you've provisioned a micro instance; which is simply a matter of them making sure you are not getting more CPU cycles than you are paying for.

Try your application on a medium instance and see if you get the same results.